# Triangle fit inside another triangle

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

Given the lengths of the sides of 2 triangles. Determine if the second triangle can fit inside the first triangle?

For more detailed info read the full problem statement below:

http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1566&locale=en

My implementation below tries all the (3!)^2 possible combinations of aligning the bases of the triangles. It then tries to shift the second triangle inside the first triangle while checking that the base of the second triangle doesn't exceed the base of the first triangle.

But I keep getting Wrong Answer(WA) #16.

[image]

The case I gave is the second image. It is obvious that if you rotate PQR to align the sides of length 2.77 and 3.0 the third vertex will not be inside triangle ABC. The side of length 4.2 can only be aligned along the side of len 5. Thus this case is satisfied only in the configuration show in the second image.

Can you help me find the bug, suggest some test cases where my algorithm breaks down. Alternative algorithms are also welcome.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const double PI = atan(1.0)* 4;

// Traingle ABC (Envelope)
double xa, ya, xb, yb, xc, yc;

// Traingle PQR (Postcard)
double xp, yp, xq, yq, xr, yr;

// Angle between sides AB and AC
double theta;

double signWrtLine(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x, double y)
{
    double A = y2 - y1;
    double B = x1 - x2;
    double C = -(A * x1 + B * y1);

    return (A * x + B * y + C);
}

bool fit()
{ 
    if ((xr > xc) || (yq > yb)) return false;

    if (signWrtLine(xa, ya, xb, yb, xq, yq) < 0) {
        double d = (yq / tan(theta)) - xq;
        return (xr + d <= xc);
    }

    return (signWrtLine(xa, ya, xb, yb, xq, yq) >= 0 && 
            signWrtLine(xb, yb, xc, yc, xq, yq) >= 0 && 
            signWrtLine(xc, yc, xa, ya, xq, yq) >= 0);
}

bool fit(double a[], double b[])
{
    // generate the 3! permutations of the envelope
    // loops i,k
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        double angle;
        double u = a[i], v = a[(i + 1) % 3], w = a[(i + 2) % 3];

        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            switch (k) {
            case 0:
                xa = 0, ya = 0;
                angle = theta = acos((u * u + v * v - w * w) / (2 * u * v));
                xb = v * cos(angle), yb = v * sin(angle);
                xc = u, yc = 0;     
                break;
            case 1:
                // reflect envelope
                swap(v, w);
                angle = theta = acos((u * u + v * v - w * w) / (2 * u * v));
                xb = v * cos(angle), yb = v * sin(angle);       
                break;
            }

            // generate the 3! permutations of the postcard
            // loops j,k
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

                double angle;
                double u = b[j], v = b[(j + 1) % 3], w = b[(j + 2) % 3];

                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    switch (k) {
                    case 0:
                        xp = 0, yp = 0;
                        angle = acos((u * u + v * v - w * w) / (2 * u * v));
                        xq = v * cos(angle), yq = v * sin(angle);
                        xr = u, yr = 0;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // reflect postcard
                        swap(v, w);
                        angle = acos((u * u + v * v - w * w) / (2 * u * v));
                        xq = v * cos(angle), yq = v * sin(angle);
                        break;
                    }

                    if (fit()) return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    double a[3], b[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) cin >> a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) cin >> b[i];

    if(fit(a, b)) cout << "YES" << endl;
    else cout << "NO" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aligning the orientation of the bases probably isn't the only way to get one triangle to fit inside the other.  The image at that link hints at a different orientation.

Comment: Seems a rather complicated way of doing this. Why not use some geometry and calculate the height of the triangles and the various angles. Then move the second ones longest side along the longes side of the first triangle until its heigth will fit. Compare angles and ensure that the first triangles longest edge has enough room for the second one (i might have explained that better).

Comment: Can you clarify which angles to compare?

Comment: Your alg alignes the longest edges of the 2 triangles and then tries to find a fit based on height. But the aligned bases don't have to be the largest ones for a fit to exits. Try the following test case:
(3 3 2; 2 2 2). If we align the longest edge of the 1st triangle(3) with the longes edge of the 2nd triangle(2) there is no fit. But if align the bases of length 2 of each tringle a fit clearly exists.

Comment: I think the image hints at a case where a fit doesn't exits. If the image represented a valid fit then there's no way to seal the envelope at 2 edges as stated in the problem.

Comment: At least one obvious mistake: your code will fail at division in lineInverse when x1==x2.

Comment: i updated the source code. but still getting WA#16.

Comment: Please take some time to go through my code. If anyone has any questions i am here to explain. Pls help me track down the bug WA#16. I have created a demo account at timus, so you can submit and test your code.
Username: timus_1566
JUDGE_ID: 110264EC
Password: 12345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use epsilon (1e-10) when comparing doubles!

Answer (score 2):

Barycentric coordinates! In detail:

Let the "envelope" triangle have vertices A, B, C; without loss of generality you can place vertex A at the origin and align the side AB with the +x axis. Use the edge lengths of the envelope triangle to find the angle at vertex A, i.e., the angle between the sides AB and AC. Using this angle, you define a new coordinate system (u,v); in this coordinate system the vertex coordinates are A=(0,0), B=(1,0) and C=(0,1).

Now, take the other triangle with vertices A',B',C', and find first the XY coordinates of the 3 vertices for each case of: (A'B', B'C', A'C') aligned with +x coordinate axis. For each such alignment, transform the other two vertices to the UV-coordinate system determined by the envelope triangle. If it happens that both of the other vertices have (u,v) coordinates with 0 <= u,v <= 1 with u+v<=1, the triangle fits within the envelope triangle.

Angle between two sides can be obtained through the sine theorem for planar triangles; though you have to be a bit careful if the angle at a vertex is obtuse (> PI/2) since the sine function is symmetric around PI/2 on the interval [0,PI]. To check whether the angle is obtuse, you also need to use the cosine theorem, though you don't need to calculate the cosine itself: if |AB|^2 + |AC|^2 > |BC|^2, the angle at A is obtuse.

I think that about sums it up.

Comment: Can you specify more clearly what do you mean by the other two vertices? If i am correct then if AC and A'C' are aligned then the other two vertices referes to B and B'. Right?

Comment: No, ABC are reference points. If you align AC and A'C', you need to transform B' and C'. (Only A' will have known coordinates (0,0) as it coincides with A.)

Comment: Let the two triangles be ABC and A'B'C'. Lets say AB and A'B' are aligned at A along the +x axis. Your algorithm checks if B' and C' are inside triangle ABC. But what about the case when C' is to the left of AC. Your alg returns false but a fit may exist if we shift the triangle A'B'C'.
Try the following test case:
(5,5,5);(3,3,2). Align bases of length 5 and 2 at A.

Comment: You have to try to align all three sides of A'B'C' and you have to perform the check in *UV coordinates*. (Alternatively, you can try to compute everything in XY coordinates, and check that C' is inside in ABC.)

Comment: My code does basically the same thing. Can your help me figure out the bug in my code. You can use the demo account i created at timus. I would be really grateful.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't guarantee that a configuration doesn't exist in which the vertices are not supposed to be aligned at the vertices of the envelope.

Comment: Try the following test:
(3, 4, 5)
(2.7784887979, 3.6878177829, 4.2)
Here a fit exits but without shifting the triangle even if we align all three sides the correct ans can't be obtained.

Comment: Sure it can. Align the right-handed triangle ABC with the side of length 3 along +x axis. Align the other triangle so that its side of length 2.7 is aligned with +x axis. The third point of the triangle lies inside of ABC. So yes, you might need to try all 9 alignments to get to the correct solution. And no, I'm not going to code that solution for you.

Comment: No! the third point isn't inside ABC if the sides of length 3 and 2.7 are aligned along +x axis. I suggest you carefully plot the points. This test case is satisfied only when you centrally align the side of length 4.2 along the side of length 5. What i want you to notice is that the edges don't have to aligned at a common vertex but centrally aligned.

Comment: I am not asking you to code the solution for me but get more familiar with my code. I suggest you try copy paste my solution at Timus using the demo account i created to get a better feel.
Pls help me find the bug. Or prove my algorithm wrong.

Comment: Can you specify which 9 alignments? As per me there are 36 possible alignments.

Comment: Try the following test: (3, 4, 5) (2.77, 3.68, 4.2)
The hundredths place is important.

Comment: The angle between the sides of length 2.77 and 3.68 is ~80 degrees. So, put that vertex at the right angle vertex (between sides 3 and 4), and align the side of length 2.77 with the side of length 3. The third vertex MUST be inside the right triangle as 3.68 is shorter than 4 AND the angle is < 90 degrees.

Comment: @zvrba let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2544/discussion-between-naximus-and-zvrba)

Answer (score 1):

```
//23/08/11 13:56
//determine if a triangle will fit inside a second triangle
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
const double pi= 3.1414926;
const double tri=180;//deg in triangle
double find_B_ang(double a,double b,double c);
double find_C_ang(double a,double b,double c);
double movetri_r , tc_ghosthor_B;
int main()
{double a=0.0,b=0.0,c=0.0,x=0.0,y=0.0,z=0.0;
double A=0.0,B=0.0,C=0.0,A1=0.0,B1=0.0,C1=0.0;// L&R base angles
double te_vert_B=0.0,te_hor_B=0.0,te_hor_C=0.0;
double tc_vert_B=0.0,tc_hor_B=0.0,tc_hor_C=0.0;
//points B and B1 are considered co-incedent
cout<<"\n\ndetermine if a triangular card will fit inside\n"
    <<"a triangular envelope\n";
//envelope dimensions    
cout<<"\nenter lengths of the sides of envelope (space between)\n";
cout<<"ensure longest of them is less than sum of other two\n";
do
{
   cin>>a>>b>>c;//the e sides
   if(c>a)swap(a,c);//sort sides in decending order
   if(b>a)swap(a,b);
   if(c>b)swap(b,c);
   if(a >(b+c))
   cout<<"WRONG...b+c must be greater than a";
}while(a >(b+c));


cout<<"\nthe sides of the envelope are "<<a<<','<<b<<','<<c<<endl;
B=find_B_ang(a,b,c);
C=find_C_ang(a,b,c);
te_vert_B=c*sin(B*pi/tri);//apex to base vertical line
te_hor_B=te_vert_B/tan(B*pi/tri);//B to vertical line
te_hor_C=a-te_hor_B;//C to vertical line

cout<<"-------------------------------------------\n";
//card dimensions
do
{
cout<<"\nenter lengths of sides of card (space between) \n"; 
cout<<"ensure longest of them is less than sum of other two\n";
do
{
   cin>>x>>y>>z;//the c sides
   if(z>x)swap(z,x);//sort sides in decending order
   if(y>x)swap(y,x);
   if(z>y)swap(y,z);
   if(x>(y+z))
   cout<<"WRONG...y+z must be greater than x\n";
}while(x>(y+z));

cout<<"\nthe sides of card are "<<x<<','<<y<<','<<z<<endl;//x is base
B1=find_B_ang(x,y,z);
C1=find_C_ang(x,y,z);
tc_vert_B=z*sin(B1*pi/tri);//apex to base vertical line
tc_hor_B=tc_vert_B/tan(B1*pi/tri);//B to vertical line
tc_hor_C=x-tc_hor_B;//C to vertical line
tc_ghosthor_B=tc_vert_B/tan(B*pi/tri);
movetri_r= abs(tc_ghosthor_B-tc_hor_B);    
cout<<"------------------------------------------------\n";
//determine and advise if card fits within envelope    
if(B1<B && tc_vert_B <(tc_hor_C + a-x)*tan(C*pi/tri))cout<<"\ntrue";
else if(B1<B && tc_hor_B< te_hor_B && tc_vert_B<te_vert_B)cout<<"true";
else if(B1>B && movetri_r<a-x && tc_vert_B<te_vert_B)cout<<"true";
else cout<<"\nfalse";
} while(x>0);
cout<<"\npress any key...";
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
double find_B_ang(double a,double b,double c)
{
 double X=0.0;
 X=((a*a)+(c*c)-(b*b));
 X/=2*a*c;
 X=acos(X);
 X*=tri/pi;
 return X; //degrees
}
double find_C_ang(double a,double b,double c)
{
 double X=0.0;
 X=((a*a)+(b*b)-(c*c));
 X/=2*a*b;       
 X=acos(X);
 X*=tri/pi;
 return X;//degrees
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might try from here - [Link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01667408). It seems that the problem is unsolved so far, so best bet to go with some heuristics to get simple cases (like checks for inscribed / circumscribed circles, aligning borders, etc) and hope for the best.

Comment: Its not unsolved - the abstract to the paper you link describes a solution :)

Comment: No mathematical constraints (plug-in formulas) have been found for this problem. But that doesn't mean that an algorithm doesn't exits. Also the URL i provided has about 100 accepted solutions.

Comment: Ah, but the problem does not require that the two triangles are congruent. (I guess the paper mistakenly uses "congruent" for "similar")